# Evaluating text in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I have a field that is text in salesforce.  I am trying to define some criteria for an action group and have the criteria set to conditions are met.  How can i evaluate this criteria to say if it contains AMER or EMEA?  The current setup does not seem to be working.  Thanks

[image: sshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For each string AMER and EMEA, create a separate condition then use the logic to set them to OR

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do you happen to have a link to some documentation? I would like to go the first route and build a formula.  I created a formula that looks for AMER and EMEA and returns true or false.  However, I receive this message.  The formula expression is invalid: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Text).  I must be thinking about this incorrectly.

Comment: Yea sorry, forgot about that. Formula is out

Comment: Great marking as complete